# c3js - D3js - Customize labels in a simple bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, charts, c3

Probably the best way to provide some context is showing the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/ron_camaron/baa0q55j/12/

```
var arrayOfDates = ['Jun 2015', 'May 2015', 'Mar 2015', 'Feb 2015', 'Jan 2015', 'Dec 2014'];
var arrayOfData = [7.25, 10.001, 10, 8.39, 10.002, 6.76]
var cautionColor = '#AB2522';
var bronzeColor = '#8C7853';
var silverColor = '#CCCCCC';
var goldColor = '#FFCC00';
var neutralColor = "#ffffff";

var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#divForGraph_1',
size: {
    height: 203,
    width: 380
},
data: {
    columns: [
        ['period'].concat(arrayOfData)
    ]
    ,
    types: {
        period: 'bar'
    }
    ,
    labels: true
    ,
    names: {
        period: 'Scoring Table'
    }
    ,
    color: function (color, d) {
        if (d.value < 4) {
            return cautionColor;
        } else if (d.value < 7) {
            return bronzeColor;
        } else if (d.value < 10) {
            return silverColor;
        } else if (d.value > 10 && d.value < 10.001) {
            return neutralColor;
        } else if (d.value >= 10.001) {
            return neutralColor;
        }

        return goldColor;
    }
    ,
    axis: {
        y: {
            label: {
                text: 'Scores',
                position: 'inner-middle'
            }
        },
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                fit: true
            }
        }
    }
}
,
axis: {
 x:{
     type: 'category',
     categories: arrayOfDates
 }
}
});

chart.axis.max({
y: 10.002
});
chart.axis.min({
y: 0
});
```

In that bar chart, there are some "special" values. I'm looking for a way to customize those values as follow:

- 10.001 = "N/S"
- 10.002 = "N/A"

The rest of values from 0 to 10 in the y axis should keep the way they are.

Another requirement is that the Y axis should show values only from 0 to 10.

Modify the DOM with jQuery might be a solution, but it's kind of hacking, I'd like to get the result using correctly the API.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In the meanwhile I had to add this piece of code to modify the DOM with jQuery:

{
              $('#divForGraph_1').find('.c3-text').each(function () {
                  var theValue = parseFloat(this.innerHTML);

                  switch (theValue) {
                      case 10.001:
                          this.innerHTML = 'N/S';
                          break;
                      case 10.002:
                          this.innerHTML = 'N/A';
                          break;
                  }
              });
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a `format` method for your data labels, like so

```
...
labels: {
    format: function (v, id, i, j) {
        if (v == 10.001)
            return "N/S";
        else if (v == 10.002)
            return "N/A";
        else
            return v;
    }
}
...
```

See http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-labels-format

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/duc8sLmo/